# Seaborn: how to make a Log base 2 axis in a small multiples plot?

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I'm doing a small multiples plot with seaborn using `relplot`:

```
g = sns.relplot(data=df,
                kind='scatter',
                col='mycol', row='arow',
                x='a', y='b', 
                hue='c',
                legend=False,
                alpha=.5)
```

I can easily tranform the axis for a log scale in base 10:

```
g.set(xscale="log")
g.set(yscale="log")
```

If I were ploting a simple plot with matplotlib I'd be able to use a log scale in base 2:

```
ax.set_xscale('log', basex=2)
ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)
```

But how do I make a Log<sub>2</sub> plot in Seaborn?

Comment: `g.axes[0,0].set_xscale('log', basex=2)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just discovered how to do it using a global function:

```
plt.xscale('log', basex=2)
plt.yscale('log', basey=2)
```